# Calling member function through const qualified object gives error as function is not marked as const?

Tags: c++, class, constants, mutable, member-functions

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
public:
    mutable int x;
    mutable int y;

    A(int k1 = 0, int k2 = 0) :x(k1), y(k2) {}

    void display()
    {
        std::cout << x << "," << y << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    const A a1;
    a1.x = 3;
    a1.y = 8;
    a1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Error: 'this' argument to member function 'display' 
        has type 'const A', but function is not marked const
```

I am just calling member function `A::display()` through `const` qualified object `a1`. So why line `a1.display()` is giving an error ?

Comment: display should be const too : void display() const

Comment: OT: You shouldn't declare members `mutable` unless you intend to change them inside of a `const` function (which has its own pros and cons).

Comment: Why don't you pass the values of `x` and `y` as arguments when constructing the object `a1`, as in `const A a1(3, 8);`?

Comment: `mutable` non-private members are suspicious

Comment: @Caleth I am not getting what are you trying to say ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane I think `A` is a poorly designed class. It looks like you applied `mutable` to `x` and `y` so that you could keep your `main`, rather than changing `main` to work with a sensible `A`

Comment: @Caleth yes I know. But I did that deliberately to understand the 
concept.

Comment: @AbhishekMane Then why are you surprised by the error? Did you not read the message?

Comment: I don't know that we don't  call non-const member function by const object ? So but error came while learning mutable keyword so I asked might be I should remove that mutable part ok my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why line `a1.display()` is giving an error ?

The `mutable` variable let you modify the member variables inside a `const` qualified function.

It does not allow you to be able to call the `non-const` qualified member function to be called via a `const` qualified instance. Therefore, you need a `const` member function there.